# NTFS write speed really slow (<15MB/s) on Ubuntu

Tags: ubuntu, ntfs

When copying large files or testing writespeed with `dd`, the max writespeed I can get is about 12-15MB/s on drives using the NTFS filesystem. I tested multiple drives (all connected using SATA) which all got writespeeds of 100MB/s+ on Windows or when formatted with ext4, so it's not an alignment or drive issue.

`top` shows high cpu usage for the `mount.ntfs` process.

AMD dual core processor (2.2 GHz)
Kernel version: `3.5.0-23-generic`
Ubuntu 12.04
`ntfs-3g` version: both `2012.1.15AR.1` (Ubuntu default version) and `2013.1.13AR.2`

How can I fix the writespeed?

Comment: Have you tried testing dd with raw drive access (on the drive or partition, doesn't matter)? Note that testing that way will destroy the filesystem and will lose any data on it. It will bypass the NTFS drivers entirely.

Comment: Yep I just did, the result is `149MB/s`.

Comment: Just out of curiosity I have to ask if this drive is one of those 4k drives and if therefore your filesystem might be unaligned somehow?!

Comment: try bonnie++ and what kernel are you using?  uname -r

Comment: bonnie++ produced similar results. read speed is faster then write (about `60mb/s`), still not nearly the possible `150mb/s` though. I added kernel and `ntfs-3g` versions to my question.

Comment: What options did you try for dd?  the block size should be at least 65536 and a large count size?  If dd runs in less than 2 min the samples size is to low.  Try:  dd if=/dev/sda of=/dev/null bs=65536 count 10000

Comment: dd if=/dev/random of=/dev/sda bs=65536 count=10000

Comment: `655360000 bytes (655 MB) copied, 49.2048 s, 13.3 MB/s`

Comment: If you double the block size to 131072 and 262144 do the speeds increase at all?

Comment: Yes, it increases a little bit but only about 1-3 mb/s. Increasing te block size further doesn't increase the speed anymore though.

Comment: How large are the files you're moving? The overhead of file creation will dominate when transferring small files.

Comment: I am copying single files with sizes between 10-15GB. No small files overhead. Also, when testing with `dd` (which ultimately writes one single file), the write rates are as bad as when copying.

Comment: I believe that the free version of NTFS-3G is crippled so that it uses 4 KiB writes with no caching, causing extremely slow write performance on SSDs and USB drives. The company behind the driver suggests buying the commercial version for better performance. Apparently no-one cares enough to actually fix (and if necessary, fork) the open source version because this problem has been around for almost a decade, ever since NTFS-3G was first released.

Comment: With the same Ubuntu 2015.04 laptop, I formatted to NTFS a 320GB external hard disk and a 32GB USB stick. Copying 2GB of pictures to the first one was taking forever (6 hours left estimated after 30 minutes), but to the second one (USB stick) it only took a minute or two. I did not change any settings between the two.

Answer (score 23):

Update: Use a newer version of Ubuntu. Newer versions of Ubuntu, e.g. 22.04+ should perform better and use bigger writes by default. Thanks to [@dmitry-grigoryev](https://superuser.com/users/427799/dmitry-grigoryev) who clarifies in an [answer below](https://superuser.com/a/1511780/388906) that

> **big_writes** was deprecated

If your version of fuse/libfuse < 3, then the original old solution provided here applies. To get the version.

```
fusermount -V
```

Solution for older Ubuntu systems (e.g. 20.04, supported until April 2025). Simply add the big_writes option, e.g.

```
sudo mount -o big_writes /dev/<device> /media/<mount_dir>
```

My Linux NAS with a low spec CPU now manages NTFS large file writes about three times faster. It improved from ~17MB/s to 50MB/s+. Even seen it peek at about 90MB/s in iotop which is probably near the external drives capability (a 2.5" USB3 HDD).

From the NTFS-3G man page:

```
 big_writes
              This option prevents fuse from splitting write buffers  into  4K
              chunks,  enabling  big  write buffers to be transferred from the
              application in a single step (up to some system limit, generally
              128K bytes).
```

A previous post was on the right track with the reference provided:

> perhaps check here for ideas on what could be causing it. http://www.tuxera.com/community/ntfs-3g-faq/#slow

The original question mentions noticing the issue with large file transfers. In my experience with copying media files or doing backups, the key option in the above FAQ was:

> Workaround: using the mount option “big_writes” generally reduces the CPU usage, provided the software requesting the writes supports big blocks.

Closing notes:

- Paragon also offers an alternative [@hi-angel](https://superuser.com/users/304864/hi-angel)'s [answer below](https://superuser.com/a/1758320/388906) provides more info if you have a newer Ubuntu version with kernel 5.15 and `ntfs3` as an option.
- Tuxera reserved the pro NTFS driver for embedded system partners and the open-sourced alternative wasn't as performant.

Comment: big_writes option made my disk go from 300kb/s to 35mb/s! Thanks!

Comment: 10 characters made a world of difference, thank you very much!

Comment: `big_writes` was [deprecated](https://github.com/libfuse/libfuse/blob/master/ChangeLog.rst#libfuse-300-2016-12-08) in 2016, however, 3 years later some distros are still using an even older version of libfuse.

Comment: Except that NTFS-3G seems to prohibit use of libfuse-3 to give the room for commercial NTFS drivers: https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/544864

Comment: Paragon doesn't work on kernel 5.10.0 giving the error `Error: Can't build driver`

Answer (score 11):

`big_writes` was [deprecated](https://github.com/libfuse/libfuse/blob/master/ChangeLog.rst#libfuse-300-2016-12-08) in 2016, the corresponding behavior is always enabled when using `libfuse` version 3.0.0 or later. On a modern Linux system, poor NTFS performance usually means that:

- the disk is fragmented
- NTFS disk compression is enabled
- inadequate mount options such as [`sync`](https://askubuntu.com/a/823091/395993) are used

Comment: How can I check whether NTFS disk compression is enabled?

Comment: Except that NTFS-3G seems to prohibit use of libfuse-3 to give the room for commercial NTFS drivers: https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/544864

Answer (score 2):

perhaps check here for ideas on what could be causing it.
https://github.com/tuxera/ntfs-3g/wiki/NTFS-3G-FAQ

This sounds a bit like the 'old days' when file io was not using DMA by default.  It's unlikely these days but is BIOS using IDE emulation for SATA drives? Because if it is emulating IDE then it may also be emulating non-DMA mode as well.

Another potential slow down is if ntfs file compression. Is compression enabled on the folder you are writing to?  If it is, that will make any new files in that folder compressed as well.

Comment: How can I test if it is using DMA? Apart from this, I have already tried out all the suggestions on the page.

Comment: Uhm, from what I have read, DMA is only relevant for IDE drives? I am only using SATA drives.

Comment: According to http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Serial_ATA#Transport_layer it sounds like DMA is the only option for SATA. Lets find out if his bios is using ide emulation

Answer (score 2):

Another likely reason is ntfs-3g you're using is slow by virtue of being a userspace driver. A kernel driver would be faster. So if you want a better speed, try the new `ntfs3` driver *(not to be confused with the older one called `ntfs` without the postfix `3`)*. [It was contributed into 5.15 Linux kernel by Paragon Software](https://kernelnewbies.org/Linux_5.15#New_NTFS_file_system_implementation), so make sure you're using 5.15 or later.

To make use of `ntfs3` when mounting, execute:

```haskell
sudo mount /dev/sdX mnt/ -t ntfs3
```

Alternatively, if you want it in fstab, you may create an entry similar to this:

```haskell
UUID=XXXXXXXXXXXXX   /path/to/mnt    ntfs3    defaults,uid=1000,gid=1000,force    0 0
```

Answer (score 0):

This is an old thread, but for people looking for a solution to the same problem: do you have cpuspeed active? ntfs-3g is CPU-hungry and in my case cpuspeed mistakenly detected a low load for processes with lots of IO waits, eventually throttling down the core and starving the driver.

Try disabling cpuspeed (if e.g. it is running as a service) and test again.

Comment: How do I determine that cpuspeed is active? Is that a daemon or a setting?

Answer (score 0):

This patch improves wrote performance for embedded devices: https://www.lysator.liu.se/~nietzsche/ntfs/

Answer (score 0):

For me under XFCE, I was observing this problem with external USB mass storage automounted via Thunar's volman. Check /etc/udisks2/mount_options.conf . Uncomment the [defaults] section label and modify ntfs_allow and ntfs_defaults to suit your needs. After that, you still need to restart the service: systemctl restart udisks2
(maybe gracefully eject your removable volumes first, before this operation)

...and then I realized that it was really my shingled HDD that was slow, in that external USB enclosure :-(

Answer (score -1):

NTFS isn't fast as EXT4.

You will always face the "fragmentation" that the Windows system has.

EXT4 can support individual files up to 16 terabytes, and volumes up to one exabyte in size. But, one of the aspects of EXT4 which contributes to better performance, though, is that EXT4 can handle a larger extents-a range of contiguous physical blocks of data. This allows it to work better with large files and reduce drive fragmentation.

Other factors include the allocate-on-flush technique used by EXT4. By delaying the allocation of data blocks until the data is ready to be written to disk, EXT4 improves performance and reduces fragmentation compared to file systems that allocate blocks earlier.

If you are not a windows user, EXT4 is strongly recommended, OSX has extFS, we don't need to follow the Windows Standard because it supports windows.

Unless you usually(daily) swap around the external USB onto the Windows system and Linux system, I will reformat the drive to EXT4.

Comment: the main issue here is the use of FUSE instead of kernel driver