# Alternative way of converting physical disk to virtual

Tags: windows-xp, virtualbox, virtualization

I have a hard disk (60 GB, about 20 used) with windows XP I want to convert to a VirtualBox hard drive. I followed the instructions in
[https://www.virtualbox.org/wiki/Migrate_Windows] but the process was painfully slow. It completed about 3 GB in two days!

I guess maybe, only maybe, was due to the fact that the disk was NTFS and the image was written to another NTFS partition in a Linux environment. The process starts fine (first GB in about ten minutes) and then becomes slower and slower

Can the **VBoxManage convertfromraw** can be used somehow in windows to direclty read from the physical hard drive and create the virtual drive? Anybody could tell me why it gets so slow in Linux (Ubuntu server 13.04)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

a) Convert the disk to VHD format using http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/ee656415.aspx
b) Even if Virtualbox can use VHD format, I found better to convert it to its native format using
`VBoxManage clonehd converted.vhd converted.vdi`

The whole problem was indeed the painfully slow NTFS writing  under Ubuntu, see
[NTFS write speed really slow (<15MB/s) on Ubuntu](https://superuser.com/questions/613869/ntfs-write-speed-really-slow-15mb-s-on-ubuntu)
or google "ntfs slow on linux" but it seems there is no penalty reading from the NTFS drive, so maybe **VBoxManage convertfromraw** when writing to and *ext* partition will do fine (not tested)

Answer (score 0):

```
"C:\Program Files\Oracle\VirtualBox\VBoxManage.exe" convertfromraw machine.dd machine.vdi
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).